# Orchard Disable Smtp Emails

Tags: email, smtp, orchardcms

I currently have a production and local development instance of my Orchard site. I want to keep SMTP outgoing emails disabled while in local development. I know how to disable emails from the admin UI, but since I typically copy my database from production to development in order to keep things up-to-date, it means I have to remember to do disable every time I copy my database.

Is there a way to disable SMTP email via 1 of the configuration files, or by some means that is not database driven?

Answer (score 2):

There is no out-of-the-box configuration. But you could implement your own.
Add an event handler in your module (some core module of your site). When the application is started the following code will be executed.

```cs
public class MyHandler : IOrchardShellEvents
{
    private readonly IModuleService _moduleService;

    public MyHandler(IModuleService moduleService)
    {
        _moduleService = moduleService;
    }

    public void Activated() {

        bool isProduction;
        if (bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsProduction"], out isProduction)) {

            var features = _moduleService.GetAvailableFeatures().ToDictionary(m => m.Descriptor.Id, m => m);

            if (features.ContainsKey("Orchard.Email"))
            {
                if (features["Orchard.Email"].IsEnabled && !isProduction) {
                    _moduleService.DisableFeatures(new string[] {"Orchard.Email"});
                }
                else if (!features["Orchard.Email"].IsEnabled && isProduction)
                {
                    _moduleService.EnableFeatures(new string[] { "Orchard.Email" });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Terminating() {}
}
```

And add a setting to your web.config file

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="IsProduction" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```